# Looping through ListBox to add multiple selected values to a single database field

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to add the multiple selected values from the ListBox into the Database. Multiple test names are to be selected for each patient (depending upon the requirements) and they are to be inserted into the column named `TestName`.

For example: If I select `ANA, CBC` for a patient, it should add BOTH values in the TESTNAME column against that patient name. 
I have tried a few things suggested on the internet, but I have been unsuccessful. I am posting my related ASP.NET code along with C# code (my latest try).

With the latest try, it throws an error saying:

> The variable name '@TestName' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

ASP.NET code for the gridview:

```
<div id="mbody">
    <div class="gview">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="gview" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="PID">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PID" HeaderText="PID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Pname" HeaderText="Pname" SortExpression="Pname" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Consultant" HeaderText="Consultant" SortExpression="Consultant" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TestName" HeaderText="TestName" SortExpression="TestName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RequestDate" HeaderText="RequestDate" SortExpression="RequestDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ReportDate" HeaderText="ReportDate" SortExpression="ReportDate" />
            </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SMCConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [PID], [Pname], [Gender], [Consultant], [TestName], [RequestDate], [ReportDate] FROM [Patient]" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Patient] WHERE [PID] = @PID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Patient] ([Pname], [Gender], [Consultant], [TestName], [RequestDate], [ReportDate]) VALUES (@Pname, @Gender, @Consultant, @TestName, @RequestDate, @ReportDate)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Patient] SET [Pname] = @Pname, [Gender] = @Gender, [Consultant] = @Consultant, [TestName] = @TestName, [RequestDate] = @RequestDate, [ReportDate] = @ReportDate WHERE [PID] = @PID">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="PID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Pname" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Consultant" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="TestName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="RequestDate" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ReportDate" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Pname" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Consultant" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="TestName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="RequestDate" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ReportDate" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
</div>
```

ListBox.aspx:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="57px" Width="270px">
    <asp:ListItem>ANA</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>ASMA</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>ASO-titres</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>ESR</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>CBC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Anti-double Stranded DNA ab</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

ListBox.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = "update Patient set TestName=@TestName, RequestDate=@RequestDate ,ReportDate=@ReportDate, Consultant=@Consultant where PID = '" + TextBox7.Text + "'";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
        {
            if (li.Selected)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestName", ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text);
            }
        }
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestDate", TextBox4.Text.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportDate", TextBox5.Text.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Consultant", TextBox6.Text);
        con.Open();
        int flag = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (flag == 1)    //On successful updation, shows a popup message
        {
            string msg = "Operation Successful";
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
            sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
            sb.Append("alert('");
            sb.Append(msg);
            sb.Append("')};");
            sb.Append("</script>");
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
        }
        else if (flag == 0)
        {
            string msg1 = "Operation Unsuccessful";
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb1 = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb1.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
            sb1.Append("window.onload=function(){");
            sb1.Append("alert('");
            sb1.Append(msg1);
            sb1.Append("')};");
            sb1.Append("</script>");
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb1.ToString());
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Maybe I need to append or concatenate or something, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Are you  inserting comma separated value into one column ?

Comment: From Bulk Insert/ update you don 't need to loop over each item and insert it to database

Comment: check this link 
http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/02/sqlbulkcopy-bulk-load-to-sql-server.html

Comment: http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2011/01/sqlbulkcopy-to-sql-server-in-parallel.html

Comment: @KhurramAli that's what i am wanting to do, insert comma separated values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add the same parameter name twice. You mentioned:

> should add BOTH values in the TESTNAME column

so I suppose you want to concatenate the selected values, if so then you can do something like:

```
var items = new List<string>();           
foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected)
    {
        items.Add(li.Text);
    }
}
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestName", string.Join(",", items));
```